# Using CSS how to create Google News type links on left, with thumbnail image on right

Tags: html, css

I need to write some CSS to create the mobile version of Google News links.

The link is on the left, and in the right is the image of the article (thumbnail).

I am enclosing an image of the required design (Google News mobile mode sample):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `display: block` and `display: inline-block;` properties

```css
.news-container {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.header-container {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
}
.image-right-container {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 30%;
  float: right;
}
.header-news-title, .left-body {
  display: block;
}
.left-body  {
  margin-top:20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  
}
.header-img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
}
.footer-date {
  margin-top:50px;
}
.title {
  font-size: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.top-img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="news-container">
  <div class="header-container">
  
    <div class="header-news-title">
      <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/496/536/354.jpg?hmac=U8UJd7a1T_tp4baF1lfEma_vCZI9XA6ou60WNjRWC4s" class="header-img">
    <div class="title">This is a news title</div>
    </div>
    <div class="left-body">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop p
    </div>
    
    <div class="footer-date">
      22 hours ago
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="image-right-container">
    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/554/536/354.jpg?hmac=D-spLEtV3F0Tjf9bJcNPOFrqI2Qv6HgRkeydjD7dug8" alt="" class="top-img">
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** [Working JSFiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/r9aw2ozd/)

Comment: Thanks Ahmad! If I need a link instead of text in the left-body I can just place the a href tag right?

Comment: Also if I need to reduce the gap between the left-body text and image on the right? How?

Comment: @sd100 yes you can add links instead

Comment: if I add smaller number of words for the url code, then there is a gap between the image on the right and url on the left. Is there anyway to reduce this gap? Thanks again!

Comment: @sd100 to reduce the gap between text and image you can add width property in `.left-body`. Please accept the answer if it solved your problem. Thanks

Comment: @sd100 to reduce the gap you have to reduce the with of `.header-container` and increase width of `.image-right-container`

Answer (score 0):

Using flexbox you can adjust the elements to the edge of the parent element.

```css
    body {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <a href="#">Your Link</a>
    <div>
        <p>Your Image</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks!  @jorgemontejo what if I need the link to be aligned to the middle of the image?

Comment: @sd100 I don't understand your question, can you explain it further?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your comment on having the link over the image. Set the image as a background image of the container and style the link to your liking.